# Document to be displayed in web using any Linux web server

Tags: webserver

Is it possible to display a word or excel document on Linux server using any web server.

What should I use to display?

Note: I Don't want to download it , having an download option is ok.

I have seen some site which display the content on the browser itself. Which are without any codes. For eg the rpm mirror sites.

Comment: It uses a server-side library to convert the document to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a web application of some sort to display the MS Office documents in a web browser. Modern web browsers can only display PDF files, and not all of them.

One such web application is Collabora Office Development Edition.
https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/

Note that it will give you full collaborative editing ability, not just viewing. Also note that it is not trivial at all to set up... but they do appear to offer a docker container which should make deployment a bit easier.